# TinyMCE - getNode() does NOT work in IE

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

This is a strange issue...

**getNode()**

Trying to add a tinyMCE button (inside *WordPress*) that opens a TinyMCEPopup window.

There I need to check the current NODE where the user has clicked inside the text -- specifically if they have clicked inside a LI node/tag.

I'm using:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().nodeName
```

Works well inside, FireFox, Chrome etc, but **NOT in IE**.

In IE I always get the node "DIV" and...

In IE it actually checks a completely different portion of the markup, like... it seems to get the parent node of the whole TinyMCE editor markup instead of where the user has clicked.

That's why it always returns a DIV.

In IE, when I click inside a LI element (in the visual view of the editor), it puts a strange frame around, which does not put my cursor inside that list element, unless I double-click the frame. See this screenshot here: http://screencast.com/t/9HVjMUvy

**getContent()**

Does also NOT seem to work in IE...

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent()
```

(IE returns always "empty", nothing selected, while all other browsers give correctly selected portion of the text)

Any ideas how to fix these?

Much appreciated!

Comment: you are using which versino of IE?

Comment: IE 8 on Windows XP, however some other people who were testing this for me on Windows had same issues. Unfortunately unknown IE versions there. It seems to be just IE. I'm on a Mac so have limited possibilities to check...

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the resize handles you may get rid of them using the following tinymce configuration paramter

```
object_resizing : false
```

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Will try. The getNode() and getContent() issue is very confusing to me how to fix and where to look...